# Can I ask something that is not a puzzle?

Tags: discussion

I want to post a question on Puzzling and I don't know if those type of question are allowed.

I want to find out if there is a way to know if you could draw a thing made from geometric figures with one pen stroke (without doing the same line twice).

It's not really a puzzle. I see it as a theoretical question and i would like to know if i can post something like that.

Comment: Well, this is a site for questions *about* puzzles and not just puzzles, so post away!

Comment: Thank you, @JoeZ.

Comment: To give you a bit more background: originally Puzzling.SE was _only_ for questions about puzzles, but there was a big (and very controversial) change last autumn and questions that were actual puzzles became vastly dominant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would consider this a puzzle... Post away.

Any question about puzzles is also on topic for this site.

Comment: (well almost any question but that isn't really pertanent)

Comment: Thank you too :)

Answer (score 3):

Not so much an answer to the general question, but a specific answer regarding the question you're thinking of posting.

If it's more theoretical than puzzle-like... that is, if you're asking whether it can be done and how to determine it in a general case... then you're probably better off asking on math.SE, as drawing a shape with one pen stroke is a concept covered by Euclidean Trails, which are part of graph theory.

Both sites will probably lead you to the information you seek, but this site will focus more on the puzzle aspect, which may or may not be what you're after.